# Best practice for working across multiple projects in a single solution

Tags: c#, wpf, service

So, I have a single Solution with 3 projects, lets call them project **A**,**B** and **C** (all 3 projects share the same namespace).

Project **A** is a WPF application, project **B** is core / global variables / functions and project **C** is a windows service.

In my head what I want to happen is project **C** will connect to the internet and download stuff, plus handle background monitoring internet statuses, which will get saved into variables stored in project **B** and then accessed by and / or bound by the WPF application in project **A**.

The issue I am having is that when the variable is populated by the windows service, on startup, it isn't visible to the WPF application. Now I have implemented the singleton pattern and also am using SetProperty to handle property update notifications, no dice (if I debug the service start the variables are correctly populated). I am sure its something involving Invoke however cannot do a BeingInvoke etc on a class?

I have added project references as follows:

- Project **C** references Project **B**
- Project **A** references Project **B**

In principle is what I am trying to do going to work or am I missing something?

Update:
To add, Project **C** the window service, is designed to monitor internet availability and set a property to false and a image to down IF a specific website isn't accessible. Project **A** is bound to those properties to show a red square around a button and a down or up image depending on the state being monitored by the service.

Comment: So A and C are both applications (one running as a service), but what is B, a class library? A and C can reference types in B, obviously, but A and C will each get a copy of B, so they won't be able to see each other's changes to variables in B (there'll be two copies). For your scenario you'll probably want only the service to reference variables in B and expose an endpoint (e.g. using WCF) that the application can then use to read and set shared variable values.

Comment: You typically use App.xaml.cs to initialize the application. The flow should be as followed: _A_ is startup and initializes _B_ with a reference to _C_ **_before_** you show the main window. When everything is initialized show the main window. _A_ uses _B_ only via binding or `ICommand`  while only _B_ uses _C_. _C_ is absolutely passive and only performs operations when _B_ requests service. _C_ never references anything in _B_. _C_ doesn't know _B_ at all. Binding source must always implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to trigger the UI to update properly.

Comment: Because of the dependencies I described, _C_ needs to persist data own its own. Instead of using _B_ for this, _C_ should use it's own data storage like memory (e.g. variables), file, database etc. When ever _B_ needs data (e.g. _A_ has to display it) _B_ has to tell _C_ to return it. Singleton is an anti-pattern, so get rid of it. You don't need it at all.

Comment: Thanks for that, just to clarify, project __B__ is set as a class library. Also I have update the question with some more information about what project __C__ does.